# Nodejs: s3 getObject for very large number of files download and archive fails

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am able to download very large ~2000 files  from s3 bucket to local disk in python using boto.s3.resumable_download_handler and boto.s3.connection. download and archive to tar file in local disk. It works.

I am trying the same functionality in nodejs:
If I am trying to download below ~500 files using s3 getObject and archive . Files gets downloaded and archived to local disk (using nodejs).

I am trying to download very large ~2000 files using s3 getObject and archive these files from the server to local disk using archive in nodejs.
I am getting s3 error: Please reduce your request rate.ServiceUnavailable: Please reduce your request rate.

Code Snippet:

```
       var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
       var archiver = require('archiver');
       var fs = require('fs');
       var OutputFileName = 'abc.zip'

       s3Client.listObjects(parameters, function(error, data) {
         var dataConts = data.Contents;
         dataConts.forEach(function(dataE) {
           var aparams = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: dataE.Key};

           archive.append(s3Client.getObject(aparams).createReadStream(),
             { name: dataE.Key }
           );

           archive.on('error', function(error) {
             throw error;
           });

           archive.on('end', function() {
             callback();
           });

           response.attachment(OutputFileName);
           archive.pipe(respose);
           archive.finalize();
        });
      });
```

can anyone let me know whether s3 and archive can be used in any other way to download and archive the very large number of files.

Comment: The tag `python` doesn't apply to this

Comment: @Yamini were you able to figure out a solution I'm needing pretty much the exact same thing but using Google Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You are being [rate limited by Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html).

That page has a guide to solve that problem. You would have to either decrease your request count or batch it, or migrate to another service such as Amazon CloudFront (CDN) or Akamai.

Comment: Thank you for your response. can you please let me know how to batch it using archive and s3 in nodejs.

Comment: That would be a separate question. Create a new question.

Comment: I don't think a new question should be necessary.  The rate limiting is fairly obviously a side effect of serious bugs in the code shown.  The archive object is clearly being misused here, calling append with a newly created S3 objecr data stream in very rapid succession, not waiting for responses, and repeatedly calling `archive.on()` inside the loop rather than before.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have moved archive.on above foreach so that it is not inside loop. Still I see the same behaviour.